# Laravel: orderBy a column with collections

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I need to OrderBy a column with collection.

I need to `orderBy(updated_at, 'desc')` all posts which owned by current logged user.

Here is my code :

```
$posts = auth()->user()->posts->sortByDesc('updated_at');
```

Here is User model :

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function posts()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

It doesn't return any errors also doesn't sort !

Any helps would be great appreciated.

P.S:

I know I can achieve this with :

```
$posts = Post::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
```

But I would like to do the same thing with collections.

Comment: Try to use `->latest()` instead of `->sortByDesc('updated_at');` its the same thing

Comment: `Method latest does not exist.`

Comment: you need to `use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`

Comment: Its not that easy `$posts = auth()->user()->posts->sortBy(function($post){return $post->updated_at;})->reverse();`. This should work.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

So this is how you sort with SQL:

```
$posts = auth()->user()->posts()->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC');
```

And with collections:

```
$posts = auth()->user()->posts->sortByDesc('updated_at');
```

I've tested the 2nd one and it works as intended for me.

*Documentation:* https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-sortbydesc 
*Its available since Laravel 5.1

Comment: For any lurkers, if you would like to sort by ascending instead, simply use `sortBy()` instead of `sortByDesc()` on collections. There is no function named `sortByAsc()`.

Comment: How about multiple order? i'm not getting the right array for multiple sort

Comment: sortByAsc() is not working for me using Laravel 8

Comment: I think sortBy defaults to Asc

Answer (score 6):

@devk is right. What I wrote in the first post is correct.

The problem was in [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) in the the view.

It needed to add this line to the Datatables options:

```
"order": [[ 5, 'desc' ]], // 5 is the `updated_at` column (the sixth column in my case)
```

So this is working fine :

```
$posts = auth()->user()->posts->sortByDesc('updated_at');
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the following to your User model

```
public function posts_sortedByDesc(){
      return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->sortByDesc('updated_at');
   }
```

Then get the posts by calling `posts_sortedByDesc` instead of  `posts`